# DataTable rows from a GridView are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using ASP.NET to make a simple Web Application connected to SQL Server...

The problem comes when I try to make a fill a GridView with data from another GridView which is connected to a table in SQL Server, I try to use a DataTable and ViewState to save the data gathered from the table that is connected to SQL Server and bind it to my second GridView.

The selected rows are correct, but the data in the columns is empty as seen in the images.

[GridView connected to SQL Server](https://prnt.sc/hgk4h2)

[After selecting some products, the second GridView is empty](https://prnt.sc/hgk4p6)

[It also happens when I try to use the RowDeleting event](https://prnt.sc/hgk4vn)

This is my code for reference:

```
public partial class menu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aceptar.Visible = false;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            HacerTablaCarrito();
        }
    }

    private void HacerTablaCarrito()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

        dt.TableName = "dtCarrito";
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nombre", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Tamanio", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PrecioUnitario", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cantidad", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        ViewState["dtCarrito"] = dt;
        gvCarrito.DataSource = dt;
        gvCarrito.DataBind();
    }

    private void AgregarNuevoRenglonAlGrid(GridViewRow item)
    {
        // Se checa si el ViewState es nulo.
        if (ViewState["dtCarrito"] != null)
        {
            // Se obtiene el DataTable del ViewState.
            DataTable dtActual = (DataTable)ViewState["dtCarrito"];
            DataRow drActual = null;

            // Se checa que el DataTable tenga al menos un dato.
            if (dtActual.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtActual.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    drActual = dtActual.NewRow();
                    drActual["Nombre"] = item.Cells[1].Text;
                    drActual["Tamanio"] = item.Cells[2].Text;
                    drActual["PrecioUnitario"] = item.Cells[3].Text;
                    // Se obtiene el TextBox que está en el Row.Cells[4] para poder sacarle el valor.
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)item.FindControl("Cantidad");
                    drActual["Cantidad"] = tb.Text;
                }

                // Se borra el renglón blanco inicial.
                if (dtActual.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtActual.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtActual.AcceptChanges();
                }

                // Se añaden los renglones creados al DataTable.
                dtActual.Rows.Add(drActual);
                dtActual.AcceptChanges();

                // Se guarda el DataTable al ViewState después de crear cada renglón nuevo.
                ViewState["dtCarrito"] = dtActual;

                // Se le da Bind al GridView con los últimos renglones agregados.
                gvCarrito.DataSource = dtActual;
                gvCarrito.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnAgregarCarrito_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in gvMenu.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox check = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("checkboxCarrito");
            if (check != null)
            {
                if (check.Checked)
                {
                    AgregarNuevoRenglonAlGrid(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void gvCarrito_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.RowIndex;

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dtCarrito"];

        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        ViewState["dtCarrito"] = dt;

        gvCarrito.DataSource = dt;
        gvCarrito.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the mistake is in my code or if it is something that i'm not contemplating.

Thanks for you help, and sorry for any typos that I may have.

Comment: you need to understand `PostBacks` also understand the page life cycle, 
`if (!IsPostBack)` you need an else and a way to rebind data use Sessions variables or write some `__DoPostBack()` javascript functions also instead of casting `ViewState` as a `DataTable` use a Session variable

Comment: @MethodMan Why would you arbitrarily say to use Session instead of ViewState? That doesn't make sense if the data is particular to that instance of the page rather than the user's entire session.

Comment: @mason why are you trolling? also session is better to use if viewstate data is  too large.. .

Comment: @MethodMan Clearly I'm not trolling: I'm pointing out that the information you have provided may be detrimental and have negative impacts that you didn't disclose because you blindly recommended it without taking the time to understand the use case.. Session makes sense to use when you have data that is specific to the user's entire session, not a specific instance of a webpage. Though of course, it's better to avoid both of them entirely.

Comment: Not sure if your issue has been resolved. I think you would be best served to not tinker with the view state until you have a better grasp of what it represents. You shoud be able to accomplish what you are after using postback with the combination of Update Panels or your own custom AJAX